# Angular 2 : Target Checkbox on div click

Tags: angular

when user clicks on div(class=unit) i want to target checkbox and mark it as checked/unchecked. also apply class unit-selected if checkbox is checked and remove class unit-selected if checkbox is unchecked.

i tried referring similar questions but nothing worked for me. can anyone help me to complete selectUnit($event)

```html
<div class="unit" (click)="selectUnit($event)" [ngClass]="{'unit-selected'}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="unit" />
        <div class="unit-number">abc</div>
        <div class="unit-desc">Description</div>
      </div>
      
<div class="unit" (click)="selectUnit($event)" [ngClass]="{'unit-selected'}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="unit" />
        <div class="unit-number">xyz</div>
        <div class="unit-desc">Description</div>
      </div>
      
<div class="unit" (click)="selectUnit($event)" [ngClass]="{'unit-selected'}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="unit" />
        <div class="unit-number">mno</div>
        <div class="unit-desc">Description</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [@Nehal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5556177/nehal)'s answer is perfectly valid and will work if there are limited '`units`', it will not scale well because you have to edit the switch statement every time, which violates the [open/closed principle of SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

If you are likely to use multiple, unknown amounts of '`units`'. Consider using [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) like so ([**Plunker here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PXaGBfbGM8OZzE8L1TkC?p=preview)):

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
      <form [formGroup]="form">
        <div formArrayName="unitArr">
          <div 
            *ngFor="let unit of units; let i = index"
            class="unit"
            (click)="onClick(i)"
            [ngClass]="{'unit-selected': unitArr.controls[i].value}">
              <input type="checkbox" formControlName="{{i}}"/>
              <div class="unit-number">{{ unit.num }}</div>
              <div class="unit-desc">{{ unit.desc }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      `,
      styles: [`.unit-selected { color: red; }`]
    })
    export class App implements OnInit{
      private units = [
        {num: 1, desc: 'Decription'},
        {num: 2, desc: 'Decription'},
        {num: 3, desc: 'Decription'},
      ]
      private form: Form

      constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}

      ngOnInit () {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          unitArr: this.fb.array(
            this.units.map((unit) => {
              return this.fb.control(false) // Set all initial values to false
            })
          )
        });
      }

      // Shorten for the template
      get unitArr (): FormArray {
        return this.form.get('unitArr') as FormArray;
      };

      onClick(i) {
        const control = this.unitArr.controls[i]
        control.setValue(!control.value) // Toggle checked
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks can you please help me understand this.from, get unitarr and onclick function step by step .... sorry but i am new to this

Comment: this.form references the property defined earlier with `private form: Form`. I assign it a new [`FormGroup`](goo.gl/5gBcXY) with the `this.fb.group` method. `get unitArr` is so that I can write `unitArr` instead of `this.form.get....` in the template. It is an [ES6 getter](goo.gl/FwnDdt). I assume you know how the `onClick` is called. It takes the `index` of the `*ngFor` loop as a param, gets the correlating control from the form array (`unitArr` as shortened earlier) and sets its value to the opposite of what it currently is by ['toggling'](goo.gl/i2h2rb) it. [tutorial](goo.gl/gkJb65)

Comment: thanks it worked for me. need one more help .... i got select all and unselect all checkbox .... how do i do it

Answer (score 2):

You can do something simple like giving each div's checkbox a name and pass the variable reference to a function triggered by `click` event, taking care of the toggle (since you want to toggle by clicking on the div, not just the checkbox itself). You can use the variable name to control `ngClass` condition and bind it to `ngModel` to handle the checkmark view.

Sample html:

```
<div class="unit" 
     (click)="toggleCheckbox('unitABC')"
     [ngClass]="{ 'unit-selected' : unitABC == true }">
   <input type="checkbox" name="unit" [(ngModel)]="unitABC">
   <div class="unit-number" >abc</div>
   <div class="unit-desc">Description</div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
unitABC = false;
unitXYZ = false;
unitMNO = false;

toggleCheckbox(currCheckbox){
  console.log(currCheckbox);
  switch(currCheckbox){
    case 'unitABC' :
      this.unitABC = !this.unitABC;
      break;
    case 'unitXYZ' :
      this.unitXYZ = !this.unitXYZ;
      break;
    case 'unitMNO' :
      this.unitMNO = !this.unitMNO;
      break;
  }
}
```

[Full demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PCO52ReqnYsoWaHzKNA5?p=preview)